# HTML Form default value is blank unless user clicks button?

Tags: php, html, forms, copy, field

For simplicity's sake lets take the following form:

```
<form>
Title: <?php echo $title; ?><input type="text" name="title" value="">
</form>
```

The $title variable contains the title of the book. In this example the output would be:

```
Title: The Hobbit <empty form field>
```

The idea is that the empty field would allow the user to change the title of the book on clicking Submit OR to copy the book's title into the field.

Problem is, I have no idea how to create the "copy into field" button.

Furthermore, this form has multiple title fields, each having the option in question so ideally, the page would not reload otherwise the user would never be able to modify all titles at once.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to go for this? Ideally I would not use javascript and stay strictly in php/html.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used PHP but can't you directly reference the value field in the input tag?  You'd have to tie it to the submit event.

Comment: So theoretically, on submit of the copy button, I would reference a php function?

Comment: Well in theory you should be able to directly grab any attribute from any tag in your website.  I'd imagine PHP has a built in functionality to do this.

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload when a user clicks submit you will have to use javascript (ajax specifically). If you want the title to be copied into the input field when you click it, you need to use javascript too.

Comment: To add, pure HTML can even reference any attribute, value, etc from any other tag, using built in commands like nextsibling, childNode, etc.

Comment: you should really use session for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you write the title in the value-attribute by default?

```
<form>
Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</form>
```

you can use css to let the input-element look like a normal Text, but on :focus it "transfers" to an input by setting a typical border.

the pro is: every input-element has the default value, so if the user sends your form, all values exist.

but, take care of escaping characters.

Comment: What an interesting approach! I'll experiment with this idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $title="Some Title"; ?>

  <form method="post">

   Title: <?php echo $title; 

    <input type="hidden" name="title_name" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">

    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['title_name'])){echo $_POST['title_name'];}?>">

    <input type="submit" value="Change Value">

 </form>
```

Comment: This changes the text displayed next to the empty field. What I want is for the empty field to populate with the text string i.e. $title.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think I understand what you want know and this should be it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
    Title: <?php echo $_POST['title']; ?><input type="text" name="title[]" value="<?php echo $_POST['title']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Change Value">
</form>
```

If you have multiple fields you'll need to put a for each loop around the title line, and only have one submit button at the bottom, and the name field will needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?= @$_POST['title'] ?>">
</form>
```